# Converting Excel file in byte array to PDF file in byte array

Tags: java, libreoffice

The LibreOffice API offers a lot of functions for URLs in order to convert files on the file system. But what if I have a file that is in an byte array and I want to convert it to a byte array from another format. Lets say I have a byte array which has the bytes of an excel file and I want to convert it to the bytes of a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have ability to comment to clarify the question, but anyway.

Maybe it sounds obvious but. 
Not sure about LibreOffice API since didn't worked with it. But for sure you can parse any Excel file  from filesystem using Apache POI library https://poi.apache.org/

And once you read the Excel file and transform it to some Java Object Model you can format a PDF file with data you want, using some of the libraries, described in this post, which fits your case the best.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java

Not sure about some magic methods, classes or so, that can transform on fly two different format byte arrays and make a copy from Excel file to PDF.
If you don't write you own of course.

Hope It can help a bit. Thanks.

Comment: You did not understand the question. He says, I have a docx file and he read it as byte array. He want to convert this byte array(docx) to pdf byte array.